# Significance testing and correlation independent observation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, assumptions

I am just wondering if these statistical testing and correlation relies on the assumption of each observation is independent?

- t-test
- f-test
- ANCOVA/ANOVA
- Pearson's correlation

My use case is to test how different each group is in our research data and if whether some feature correlates with the grouping. Some of the participant data is being collected more than once (looking into the progression after period of time) and if the observations should be independent, then I would need to select one observation for each of these cases.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The terms t-test and F-test are imprecise as there are several tests that use the t-, and F-statistic, and all these are called t- and F-tests in most literature. What precise tests do you mean (model? null hypothesis?)? For example if you use a t-test to compare two groups, there is a version for independent data, and one where observations are paired/matched, meaning that there can be dependence between the two observations paired together.

Comment: Regarding Pearson correlation, the standard problem is to test the correlation between two variables, which of course you don't have to assume to be independent (otherwise you'd assume correlation zero and wouldn't need to test this - although the null hypothesis does assume independence and the test will tell you whether the data are compatible with this) - however, the different observations, each having values on both variables, are modelled to be independent.